# Can't sync android emulator with flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]
Could Not Find C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\AdbWinApi.dll.dat
The directory name is invalid.
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 9139): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Error waiting for a debug connection: ProcessException: adb returned error:
The directory name is invalid.
Could Not Find C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\AdbWinApi.dll.dat

Command: C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:0 tcp:42601
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.
Exited (sigterm)
[image]

Comment: From my experience I will say that for a start it is better to use `Android Studio`, and not VS code. Download, install `Android Studio`. Also in terminal run command `flutter doctor` attach a screenshot of this command's execution

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by the following 3 steps:
1 remove the sdk and emulator.
2 install again the sdk and emulator.
3 restart my computer
and then then solved it